# If EOT and WOFF do not work on Android devices, is Typekit a backup?

Tags: font-face, typekit

I'm looking to use a purchased web font that comes with WOFF and EOT font formats for web on a responsive website.  Needless to say the format needs to work on all devices including Android.

I'm working with developers and they are telling me WOFF and EOT are not supported on such device.

My question is, that if it is possible to host through typekit, does this make a difference?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in stating that the default Android Browser does not support WOFF or EOT fonts. The only font format supported widely by Android devices is TTF/OTF. Some newer (3.0+) builds of Android will also support SVG fonts. Typically, a web font will come packaged with all three major formats: WOFF, EOT, and TTF/OTF. These three filetypes, when used with a correct @font-face in your CSS, will ensure that the font works correctly on nearly every device/browser in significant use today.

Your webfont should have come with all three major file formats. If not, you can use a tool such as the [Font Squirrel Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to obtain it. Hosting through typekit may also provide a solution, but typekit isn't free in some cases unlike doing the conversion yourself.

Comment: TTF was the solution for me with Android 4.0 (WOFF didn't work)

Answer (score -4):

try this implementation

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'OpenSans';
  font-weight: 300%;
}
```

for more information check out this example https://github.com/ttibensky/BulletProof-font-face-implementation